# replace text with icons

Tags: support, script

Exist any way to replace text with icons?

Like this example:

[image]

I have tried to re-write/replace the html from an extension in the site but I have not achieved anything functional; with the relative little documentation that has the use and implementation of this: https://stackoverflow.design/product/resources/icons/